# Typo3 ExtensionProblem with database: can't see values despite a connection

Tags: php, mysql, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I am trying to migrate my own extension from an older (typo3 6.2.31) version to the latest (Typo3 8.7.19). The extension includes a table with uploaded videos.

In my database the records are alle persistent.

I only can see a row for each video like in database, but without values. Using debugger utility I can see all attributes, like 'title'. But these are all empty except the uid.

I doublechecked the controller and the model and this looks fine to me.
Maybe there are changes in the tca settings or ext_tables.php which I need to perform.
What else can cause this problem?

Best Regards

Let me know if or witch code you need to see to give a more detailled answer and I will add it to my post

Class/Namespace Controller

```
namespace TYPO3\Videoverwaltung\Controller;

class VideoController extends 
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
```

Class/Namespace Model

```
namespace TYPO3\Videoverwaltung\Domain\Model;

class Video extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{
```

Class/Namespace VideoRepository

```
namespace TYPO3\Institutsvideoverwaltung\Domain\Repository;

class VideoRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository {
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In TYPO3 Extbase only those fields of a model are filled, that are also listed in the TCA. Make sure, that any fields, you have in the model, also appears in the according TCA.

Comment: Thank you for ur quick response. I checked this issue. I have all the fields in the TCA too.

Comment: Please also make sure, that the TCA files conform to the current specification. Some hints can be found here: https://usetypo3.com/upgrading-projects.html#c377

Comment: @feeela thank you! I'm gonna check if I can make some changes in the TCA following the Information in your link